# How are source ports determined and how can I force it to use a specific port

Tags: networking, port, tcp

When I connect to https://www.google.co.uk this changes to 216.58.198.228:443. Then a connection to me opens on [My IP Address]:63998.

My question is how is 63998 port choosen and is there a way of forcing it to be 63999.

Comment: *is there a way of forcing it to be 63999* Do you have any reason for trying to do this?

Comment: If you're writing an application, you can open any (unused) source port that you want. But it's not a good idea and not clear why you want this?

Comment: @pjc50 Indeed, this question seems like it might be having an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I"ve submitted an edit to change the title to say "source" rather than "local", as destination port numbers are "local" to the destination machine, but the source of the initial TCP SYN packet is unambiguously that of the initiator of the connection.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### How are local ports determined

The port number is chosen by the TCP implementation software from a range of port numbers called [Ephemeral Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

The exact mechanism for choosing the port number and the range to be used is Operating System dependent.

---

#### Is there a way of forcing it to be 63999.

This can be done by changing the configuration of the TCP implementation software.

Instructions on configuring the [Ephemeral Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) range for a variety of different Operating Systems can be found at [Changing the Ephemeral Port Range](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html#Changing).

- Instructions for Linux and Windows are included in this answer below for reference.

However, it is not a good idea to restrict the range to a single port, for example `63999`.

- In fact on Windows this is not possible as:

  > The minimum range of ports that can be set is 255.

---

#### The Ephemeral Port Range

> A TCP/IPv4 connection consists of two endpoints, and each endpoint
>   consists of an IP address and a port number.  Therefore, when a client
>   user connects to a server computer, an established connection can be
>   thought of as the 4-tuple of (server IP, server port, client IP,
>   client port).
>
> Usually three of the four are readily known -- client machine uses its
>   own IP address and when connecting to a remote service, the server
>   machine's IP address and service port number are required.
>
> What is not immediately evident is that when a connection is
>   established that the client side of the connection uses a port number.
>   Unless a client program explicitly requests a specific port number,
>   the port number used is an ephemeral port number.
>
> Ephemeral ports are temporary ports assigned by a machine's IP stack,
>   and are assigned from a designated range of ports for this purpose. 
>   When the connection terminates, the ephemeral port is available for
>   reuse, although most IP stacks won't reuse that port number until the
>   entire pool of ephemeral ports have been used.
>
> So, if the client program reconnects, it will be assigned a different
>   ephemeral port number for its side of the new connection.

Source [The Ephemeral Port Range](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html#Windows)

---

#### Changing the Ephemeral Port Range

**Linux:**

> Linux allows you to view and change the ephemeral port range by simply
>   using the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`.  For example,
>   this shows the default configuration on a kernel 2.2 system:
>
> ```
> $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 
> 1024 4999
> ```
>
> To change this to the preferred range, you could do (as superuser):
>
> ```
> # echo "49152 65535" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
> ```
>
> Note that you would need to do this each time the system boots, so be
>   sure to add a line to a system startup script such as `/etc/rc.local`
>   so your range is always used.
>
> Also note that the Linux 2.4 kernel will default the range of 32768
>   through 61000 if adequate kernel memory is available, so changing the
>   range may not be necessary on newer Linux systems.
>
> Finally, also note that you may be able to use the `sysctl` interface
>   to change the settings rather than using the `/proc` filesystem. The
>   name of the `sysctl` parameter is "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range". 
>   Edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file if you have it, or have a startup
>   script run the `sysctl` command manually if you want to change this
>   parameter using `sysctl`.

**Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008 and newer:**

> As of Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, Windows now uses a large
>   range (49152-65535) by default, according to Microsoft Knowledgebase
>   Article [929851](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851/). That same article also shows how you can change
>   the range if desired, but the default range is now sufficient for most
>   servers.

Source [Changing the Ephemeral Port Range](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html#Changing)

> You can view the dynamic port range on a computer that is running
>   Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 computer by using the following
>   `netsh` commands:
>
> ```
> netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
> netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport udp
> netsh int ipv6 show dynamicport tcp
> netsh int ipv6 show dynamicport udp
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> - The range is set separately for each transport and for each version of IP.
> - The port range is now truly a range with a starting point and with an endpoint.
> - Microsoft customers who deploy servers that are running Windows Server 2008 may have problems with RPC communication between servers
>     if firewalls are used on the internal network.
> - In these cases, we recommend that you reconfigure the firewalls to allow for traffic between servers in the dynamic port range of `49152`
>     through `65535`.
> - This range is in addition to well-known ports that are used by services and by applications.
> - Or, the port range that is used by the servers can be modified on each server.
>
> You adjust this range by using the `netsh` command, as follows:
>
> ```
> netsh int <ipv4|ipv6> set dynamic <tcp|udp> start=number num=range
> ```
>
> This command sets the dynamic port range for TCP. The start port is
>   number, and the total number of ports is range. The following are
>   sample commands:
>
> ```
> netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=1000
> netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=1000
> netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=1000
> netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=1000
> ```
>
> These sample commands set the dynamic port range to start at port
>   10000 and to end at port `10999` (1000 ports).
>
> Notes:
>
> - The minimum range of ports that can be set is `255`.
> - The minimum starting port that can be set is `1025`.
> - The maximum end port (based on the range being configured) cannot exceed `65535`.
> - To duplicate the default behavior of Windows Server 2003, use `1025` as the start port, and then use `3976` as the range for both TCP and
>     UDP. This results in a start port of `1025` and an end port of `5000`.

Source Microsoft Knowledgebase Article [929851](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851/):

**Windows XP and older:**

> For older Windows operating systems (Windows XP and older), Windows
>   uses the traditional BSD range of 1024 through 4999 for its ephemeral
>   port range.  Unfortunately it appears that you can only set the upper
>   bound of the ephemeral port range.  Here is information excerpted from
>   Microsoft Knowledgebase Article [196271](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;196271):
>
> - Start Registry Editor (`Regedt32.exe`).
> - Locate the following key in the registry:
>
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`
> - On the "Edit" menu, click "Add Value", and then add the following registry value:
>
>   Value Name: `MaxUserPort` Data Type: `REG_DWORD` Value: `65534` (for
>     example)
>
>   Valid Range: `5000-65534` (decimal) Default: `0x1388` (5000 decimal)
>
>   Description: This parameter controls the maximum port number used
>     when an application requests any available user port from the system.
>     Normally, ephemeral (that is, short-lived) ports are allocated between
>     the values of `1024` and `5000` inclusive.
> - Quit Registry Editor.
>
> Note: There is another relevant KB article ([812873](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;812873)) which claims
>   to allow you to set an exclusion range, which could mean that you
>   could exclude ports `1024-9999` (for example) to have the ephemeral
>   port range be `10000-65534`. However, we have not been able to get
>   this to work (as of October 2004).

Source [Changing the Ephemeral Port Range](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html#Changing)

Comment: For at least windows is seems like it is possible to restrict the port range system wide. In most cases this is probably a bad idea, especially restricting it to one port would be: [See KB 929851](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929851), the commands listed at least work on Windows 7.

Comment: @Seth Yes. I was reluctant to mention this since the OP didn't mention his OS and I didn't want to expand the answer to cover N operating systems ...

Comment: You're right about that. After all there are plenty of operating systems. It's just something I stumbled across while originally trying to answer this question. As your answer was up faster I just thought I'd add it. It's a really well written answer! :) Just added it as a hint that sometimes changing the configuration is sufficient rather than reprogramming (maybe my understanding is just different - for me that sounds akin to recompile).

Comment: @Seth Thanks. Good point. I will change it to read reprogramming/reconfiguring.

Comment: In fact, in Linux too it is very simple: just do *echo "49152 65535" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range*. It is so simple that it can be done on a *per-command* basis.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Answer updated to link to configuration instructions.

Comment: Rather than changing the ephemeral port range it would be much better to have the application call the `bind` system call before it calls `connect`. Some applications have an option to do that, other applications do not.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae it might be possible on a per-command basis but it's always a system setting. Windows and Linux are similar in that regard.

Comment: Just a side note/use case for changing the ephemeral port range by excluding ports: [Rootkit Hunter (rkhunter)](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/) checks for backdoor ports, some of which lay in the default ephemeral port range. This can cause random false positives. I created the file /etc/sysctl.d/10-rkhunter-reserved-ports.conf containing the following line to fix this:
net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports = 13000,14856,25000,29812,31337,32982,33369,47107,47018,60922,62883,65535

Comment: @ggb667 What is your question?

Answer (score 10):

David Postill's answer is perfectly right. I would like just to add to it, by stressing that changing the ephemeral port range in *Linux* is so simple, that the OP has an affirmative answer.

You change the EPR as follows:

```
echo "40000 60000" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

and you can select port 50000 (as an example) with the following script:

```
OLD_RANGE=$(cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range)
MY_PORT=50000
echo "$MY_PORT $MY_PORT" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
sudo -u SomeUser SomeApplication  & 
echo $OLD_RANGE" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

One caveat here: since there is a single port in the range, another application might snatch it away from you between the execution of the third and the fourth lines above; also, even if there is no race condition, you will paralyze all other applications until you restore a large EPR, which is why I restored the original range as soon as possible.

Thus, **if** the OPs' operating system had been Linux, the answer would have been that it could easily be done.

Amazingly, this is not as straightforward on BSDs, some of which do not even have a runtime kernel setting for the EPR. MacOS X, FreeBSD and OpenBSD require modifying  the file */etc/sysctl.conf*, but they have different choices for the EPR.

Regardless of the above and of the OS, the fact that something *can* be done does not mean it *ought* to be done: why on Earth do you need this? I cannot think of  a single use case.

Comment: For Linux example +1.

Comment: Hehe. BSD/OS requires recompiling the kernel :)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's a **major** bummer.

Comment: There is a flaw in your code example. Your type cast is very misplaced. Additionally it would be a good idea to make `BIND_PORT` optional, such that the code still can be used in exactly the same way as the original. I think `htons(bind_port_env ? atoi(bind_port_env) : 0)` would do the right thing.

Comment: Um, isn't this code firing up the application and restoring the old range in parallel? (That might not work too well :-) And there's a quote missing.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth adding that Linux kernel also has

`net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports`

knob that does somewhat opposite but nevertheless it might be very useful because that way you can "punch a hole" for services that open specific port(s) in otherwise ephemeral range of ports.

Brief excerpt from the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt):

> Specify the ports which are reserved for known third-party
>       applications. These ports will not be used by automatic port
>       assignments (e.g. when calling connect() or bind() with port
>       number 0). Explicit port allocation behavior is unchanged.
>
> The format used for both input and output is a comma separated
>       list of ranges (e.g. "1,2-4,10-10" for ports 1, 2, 3, 4 and
>       10). Writing to the file will clear all previously reserved
>       ports and update the current list with the one given in the
>       input.